# Shutting down Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I was reading up details of Kafka High level consumer in this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example) and saw the below statement -

> In practice, a more common pattern is to use sleep indefinitely and
>   use a shutdown hook to trigger clean shutdown.

Are there any examples for doing this or pointers which could help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will be an example of an infinite loop

```
public void run() {
    try {
      consumer.subscribe(topics);
      while (true) {
          ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        //do something
      }
    } catch (WakeupException e) {
      // do nothing we are shutting down 
    } finally {
      consumer.close();
    }
  }

  public void shutdown() {
    consumer.wakeup();
  }
}
```

And this will be your shutdown hook.

```
@PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        addShutdownHook(); 
    }

 private void addShutdownHook(){
   Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                shutdown();
            }
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Nautilus , please can you explain the use of this addShutdownHook? When will it get triggered and how is it triggered?

Comment: Punter Vicky, read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread) I think it will be much more clear than any explanation that I can give in a comment here. Also another option to create a shutdown hook is to annotate the shutdown() with @PreDestroy (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html)